# In BevyEngine, which direction is up?

Tags: bevy

It isn't clear which coordinate system the engine uses.

I've tried looking through the documentation and the book.

Comment: I have only done 2D projects with bevy, but X is left/right, Y is up/down, and Z is forward/backward.

Answer (score 2):

The reference you want is in the [Bevy Cheatbook: 3.1. Coordinate System](https://bevy-cheatbook.github.io/features/coords.html).

- X goes from left to right (+X is "right")
- Y goes from bottom to top (+Y is "up")
- Z goes from far to near (+Z is "toward the viewer")

The cheatbook goes on to add that "for UI, Bevy follows the same convention as most other UI toolkits, the Web, etc." in which Y begins at the top (+Y is "down").

There's a cool graphic to accompany the article, which I hope I'm allowed to share here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Positive Y axie.

Search the Bevy cheatbook

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).